# ZF2 - ServiceManager conflict with unit testing in Module.php

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

In Module.php, i implemented the code to check for authentication of a user before allowing access to restricted pages.

Here is my Module.php

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;

class Module
{
    protected $whitelist = array('authenticate', 'home');

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        $authService = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
        $whitelist = $this->whitelist;
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function ($e) use ($whitelist, $authService) {
            $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
            //No route match, this is a 404
            if (!$routeMatch instanceof RouteMatch) {
                return;
            }
            //Route is whitelisted
            $matchedRouteName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
            if (in_array($matchedRouteName, $whitelist)) {
                return;
            }
            //User is authenticated
            if ($authService->hasIdentity()) {
                return;
            }
            //Redirect users
            $router = $e->getRouter();
            $url = $router->assemble(array(), array(
                'name' => 'authenticate'
            ));
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
            $response->setStatusCode(302);
            return $response;
        }, -100);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function ($serviceManager) {
                    return $serviceManager->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');

                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in browser, but when running the unit test it throws the following error.

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default
```

The problem is the service manager in onBoostrap is not able to initialize authentication adapter, this is the code with problem

```
$authService = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
```

When i disable $authService all unit test runs successfully, i am not able to figure out the exact issue causing this, what could be the possible issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you run your tests, you have to configure your entity managers.

With the auth module you have a doctrine entity manager which is not configured yet in your bootstrap tests. Is it ?

By default you should have `doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default` but it's not that you have in your error you have this one : `doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default`

I guess you have to add an entity manager in your test.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the issue was i was not loading DoctrineOrmModule for tests.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar at least how you can loa DoctrineOrmModule on tests?